# Не работает центрирование текста

Tags: html, css

Пытался выровнять текст по центру блока при помощи **vertical-align и text-align,**

но текст не хочет выравниваться по центру. Каким образом это исправить?

```css
#block{
background: gold;
height: 100px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

#text{
font-size: 25px;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id ="block">                  
<div id ="text">
Заяц и волк =)
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align` - не предназначен для выравнивание текста по центру по оси `Y`.

Это свойство выравнивает элемент относительно родителя и окружающего его текста...

```css
#block {
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

span.s {
  vertical-align: -50px;
  font-size: 35px;
}

span.p {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <span class="s">
            class="s"
        </span>
  <span class="p">
            class="p"
        </span>
</div>
```

Вариант два

```css
#block {
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

span.s {
  vertical-align: 20px;
  font-size: 35px;
}

span.p {
  vertical-align: -20px;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <span class="s">
            class="s"
        </span>
  <span class="p">
            class="p"
        </span>
</div>
```

что бы было понятнее

```css
#block {
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

span.s {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <span class="s">Заяц и волк =)
   </span> incidunt nulla dignissimos
</div>
```

еще вариант

```css
#block {
  background: gold;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

span.s {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  <span class="s">Заяц и волк =)
   </span> incidunt nulla dignissimos
</div>
```

Comment: Последние два варианта не работают =)

Answer (score 2):

И не должно работать.
**UPD** заставил работать с vertical-align.

```css
#block{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gold;
}

#text {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id ="block">                  
<div id ="text">
Заяц и волк =)
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ух ты, отличное решение при помощи grid layout =) Но можно ли  центрирование текста реализовать на vertical-align и text-align)? И почему мой код не работает)?

Comment: UPD. Теперь работает с vertical-align: middle (но так делать ненужно). Вообщем почитайте об этом свойстве, лучше на английском.

Comment: Потому что,`vertical-align` применяется к строчным элементам и выравнивает элемент относительно родителя, а сам текст не является  элементом

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, то к строчным элементам относится же div ?

Comment: div, блочный элкмент

Comment: А если задать div display:inline, то это сделает ли div строчным элементом?

Comment: Какой элемент будет родительским тексту Заяц и волк =) div c id "text" или с "block"

Answer (score 0):

Пример на flex

```css
#block{
background: gold;
height: 100px;
margin-bottom:10px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;

}

#text{
font-size: 25px;
align-self: center
}
```

```html
<div id ="block">                  
<div id ="text">
Заяц и волк =)
</div>
</div>
```